# Script called by another system doesn't run correctly

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, kvm, freenas

I am trying to write some scripts for graceful shutdowns from my UPS. My UPS is hooked up to my freenas system. I also have a KVM server running KVM on Ubuntu 18.04, and that is where I'm having some issues. I have the following script on my freenas to call the shutdown script on my KVM server:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 /opt/shutdown.sh
```

Then the `shutdown.sh` script on my KVM server is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configure timeout (in seconds).
TIMEOUT=300
VIRSH=/usr/bin/virsh

# List running domains.
list_running_domains() {
        $VIRSH list | grep running | awk '{ print $2}'
}


echo "Try to cleanly shut down all running KVM domains..."

# Create some sort of semaphore.
touch /tmp/shutdown-kvm-guests

# Try to shutdown each domain, one by one.
list_running_domains | while read DOMAIN; do
        # Try to shutdown given domain.
        $VIRSH shutdown $DOMAIN
done

# Wait until all domains are shut down or timeout has reached.
END_TIME=$(date -d "$TIMEOUT seconds" +%s)

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $END_TIME ]; do
        # Break while loop when no domains are left.
        test -z "$(list_running_domains)" && break
        # Wait a litte, we don't want to DoS libvirt.
        sleep 1
done

# Clean up left over domains, one by one.
list_running_domains | while read DOMAIN; do
        # Try to shutdown given domain.
        $VIRSH destroy $DOMAIN
        # Give libvirt some time for killing off the domain.
        sleep 3
done
```

I found the KVM script here [enter link description here](https://github.com/kumina/shutdown-kvm-guests/blob/master/shutdown-kvm-guests.sh)

The KVM shutdown script works great when I SSH directly into the KVM server, however, when the freenas system calls the script over SSH it doesn't seem to work. I can see the echos, so I know it's getting called. I know it's not the best practice, but I set permissions on the script to 777 just to see if I can get it working, but that still doesn't seem to help. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit. It actually had nothing to do with SSH or permissions. I had to add `LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system` before all of the virsh commands on the KVM server script.